# How to add variables in one column?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Please tell me how I can configure the editor(VSCODE) so that the variables are in one column? what need to do?

```
var a,
    b,
    c;
let a,
    b,
    c;
const a = 1,
      b = 2,
      c = 3;
```

Comment: You can check all the options of the js-beautify here : [VSCodeBeautify](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify) and here [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) maybe you want this : `html.format.preserveNewLines` instead of having them in a single line.

Comment: Why would you want this? Declaring vars as single statements is easier to maintain since you don't have to worry about where the commas and final ; comes when adding or removing a variable. It's also easy to forget a comma for example and all of a sudden your var becomes global instead of scoped to a function in case that's where you declare them.